# Ist die Nutzung von »Kompendium« in diesem Kontext korrekt?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Ich arbeite an einer Seite für eine Programmiersprache, die eine kurze Einführung vermittelt (Installation, erste Schritte) und auf nützliche Quellen, Projekte u. Ä. verweisen soll. Meine Frage ist, ob es korrekt ist, diese als *Kompendium* zu bezeichnen.

Wikipedia beschreibt ein Kompendium wie folgt:

- ein kurz gefasstes Lehrbuch
- ein kurz gefasstes Nachschlagewerk

Meine Seite ist kein Lehrbuch im klassischen Sinne, da es nicht die Sprache selbst erklärt, sondern nur eine kurze Einleitung bietet und bspw. auf Online-Bücher verweist.

Ein Nachschlagewerk wäre sie, da der Programmierer auf die Seite kommt und zu dem Anwendungsbereich XYZ eine Liste von Projekten findet, die ihm bei der Problemlösung unterstützen können.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich meine *Kompendium* hat immer den Anspruch ein Thema vollständig abzudecken. Diese Eigenschaft wäre für mich wichtiger als die Form. Ich schätze, dass deine Seite diese Eingenschaft nicht erfüllt.

Allerdings, glaube ich, umfasst diese Aufassung nur einen Teil der Wortbedeutung. Wikipedia scheint es als *exzessives Handbuch* aufzuführen.

Ich würde sagen, ein *Kompendium* ist mehr als ein *Tutorial*, aber weniger als eine alles abdeckende Beschreibung. Es erscheint mir als etwas, in dem **sehr viel** Materie, Aspekte und so weiter jeweils **kurz** behandelt wird.

Comment: Willkommen beim deutschsprachigen Stackexchange. Schöne Antwort, weiter so!

Comment: Danke für die Meinung. Die Definition als "exzessives Handbuch" wäre mit dem Begriff des Kompendiums nicht wirklich vereinbar, da ich nicht die Aspekte der Sprache selbst behandeln will, sondern vielmehr die peripheren Eigenheiten vermitteln und auf sie eingehen möchte. Das wären mehr die ersten Schritte oder allgemeine Infos zum Ökosystem einer Programmiersprache.